# Crystal report connection with local DB client side issue

Tags: c#, .net, deployment, crystal-reports, setup-deployment

I have created a desktop application and designed some reports using sap crystal report. First to design report I used database from sql server management studio and put all the field on report. But I have to deploy it client side with localDB after connecting my application with local db I am able to access database on my forms but cant getting data on report.
I fetched data in datatable then I am setting datatable as datasource for report but I am getting error.

> Failed to open the connection Details: Database Vendor Code:4060

Please provide me correct answer as soon as possible.

Comment: Welcome. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) then people can help you better. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

i faced same type of problems and fixed mine by the following steps:

1. Change the command again.
2. Log off then login to the DB.
3. Verify the DB.

This worked fine for me. I'm using crystal reports 10.